# ListBlobsSegmentedAsync does not list soft deleted blob

Tags: c#, azure

I am trying to get the list of all soft deleted blobs from a container using the below code.
However I always get a result of non deleted blobs even when I have used the BlobListingDetails.Deleted option to include the soft deleted blobs.

```
CloudBlobContainer.ListBlobsSegmentedAsync( 
                    "", 
                    true, 
                    BlobListingDetails.Deleted
                    null,
                    continuationToken,
                    requestOptions,
                    new OperationContext());
```

Answer (score 0):

After reproducing from our end we could able to retrieve the soft deleted blob list using the below code.

```
BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient("<CONNECTION_STRING>");

BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient("<CONTAINER_NAME>");

foreach (BlobItem blob in containerClient.GetBlobs(BlobTraits.None, BlobStates.Deleted))
{
         if(blob.Deleted==true)
         {
                Console.WriteLine(blob.Name);
         }
}
```

**RESULTS:**

[image]

[image]

**REFERENCES:** [Manage soft-deleted blobs - MSFT Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/soft-delete-blob-manage?tabs=dotnet#manage-soft-deleted-blobs)